# EF 6 Entity sets are missing from Linq intellisense

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My EF6 EDMX model contains some entities which have public access and are non abstract with Name and Entity set name defined, But they are missing from this linq:

```
using MyMVC.Data;
using (var context = new MyMVCEntities())
{
   context. // No entities in intellisense
   context.Set<Products> // No intellisense for products
}
```

Why it is like this?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the model EDMX and created a new one from database and now I have the entities in the Linq  Queries.